# Attaching powershell file with VS Code Extension while publishing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a VS Code extension that executes a PowerShell file, it works flawlessly in dev environment. However, once I have published the extension with **vsce package** >> **vsce publish** in the marketplace, it stops working. It seems myScript.ps1 is not uploaded while publishing. I think I need to tell explicitly to include my PowerShell script but not sure how.

Note: myScript.ps1 is located inside src>helper folder.

Comment: What about the file `.vscodeignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .vscodeignore indeed ignores most of the file that ships with boilerplate, even the src folder was included there. The package.json file however indicates files which are under **out** folder will be shipped. So, I put my helper folder inside the **out** folder and that way when I do **vsce package >> vsce publish** it now ships my script.